# AssertionError: reactor already installed

Tags: python

Today I just installed `ldtp` and when I try to import it, I get this error:

```
import ldtp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ldtpd/__init__.py", line 55, in main
    glib2reactor.install()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/glib2reactor.py", line 46, in install
    installReactor(reactor)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/main.py", line 24, in installReactor
    "reactor already installed"
  AssertionError: reactor already installed
```

But I don't know what I have done to install this reactor.

I had tried to remove `python-twisted-web` and install again or reboot  my laptop, but neither of them make any sense.

`ldtp 2` is installed from `git clone` and I followed the installation instructions on the Git page.

Twisted is `python-twisted-web.x86_64` (8.2.0-3.2.el6)

So how can I uninstall the reactor or do anything to solve this error?

Comment: How you installed `ldtp` ?

Comment: @RahulKP from git clone from Git page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay , I finally solved this problem by adding a "#" at the beginning of

/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ldtpd/**init**.py , line 55 , in main

```
glib2reactor.install()
```

To avoid it installing a new reactor.

I knew it wasn't the real way to clean the error but it do solved problem and my ldtp runs well.

If anybody have any idea , pleas let us know.